# How object can be created outside main function?

Tags: c++

I don't understand the output of this code:

- How the object `a1` of class `A` is created and constructor is called?
- Why the object `a1` is created outside the `main` function ?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;     
class A
{
    public:
    A(int i)
    {
        std::cout<<"I am in A Class "<< i <<endl;
    }
};
 A a1(8);

int main()
{
    A a(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
I am in A class 8
I am in A class 9
```

Comment: Global objects’ constructors are called before main(), and their destructors called after main() returns.  It has to be that way otherwise they would not be in a valid state for the code within main to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically implementation dependent.

Except that a1 has to be constructed before it gets used.

In your example, main() isn't using a1.  However, a simple way for a C++ implementation to make sure that a1 is constructed before it gets used is to just have a1 (and any non-local non-inline variables with static storage) be constructed/initialized before main().

Reference: "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized"

Comment: `main` is such a function, so the fact that this global is in the same translation unit as `main` means that its initialization is guaranteed to complete before `main` is entered

Answer (score 1):

> whats the reason that object can create first outside main function

In your example `a1` has global namespace scope and has [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).
It is constructed at program startup and therefore you see

```
I am in A class 8
```

printed out before

```
I am in A class 9
```

Answer (score 0):

`a1`is a global variable. Globals are constructed before `main` is invoked.